# Use chart.js with freemarker tamplates

Tags: javascript, chart.js, freemarker

I'm using chart.js in a freemarker template. But there is an issue when using labels args of chart.js.

```
labels: {
    position: "outside",
    render: (args) => {
        return `${args.label}`;
    },
    textMargin: 10,
}
```

The issue is when I'm using `${args.label}`, it gives a ftl error. Any solution for use this inside ftl?

Comment: What is the error, and where was args defined?

Answer (score 0):

The labels arg is not supposed to be an object, the labels arg is expecting an array of labels, the styling of these labels need to be done in the options object for that specific scale